# how to combine two columns in SQL Server 2005

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I am having some issues combining two columns in the same table in SQL Server 2005

```
select cast( FirstName as varchar)+'-'+cast( secondName as varchar) 
from table
```

how to I remove any spaces between the two fields

Comment: It's advisable to explicit declare the size of the varchar

Answer (score 2):

Presumably, the names are already strings, so conversion is useless.

If you have unnecessary spaces, remove them with `ltrim()` and `rtrim()`:

```
select ltrim(rtrim(firstname)) + '-' + ltrim(rtrim(lastname))
```

Comment: TSQL now (2017) has a trim function that does both left and right trimming. Just a note for everyone else - 2005 is way out-of-date